# JPA: ManyToMany where in

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

```
class MyEntity {

    ... important fields here

    @ManyToMany
    private List<AnotherEntity> anotherEntities = new ArrayList<AnotherEntity>();

}
```

So what I want to do is to write a query

```
TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = em.createQuery("from MyEntity me where :anotherentity in me.anotherEntities", AnotherEntity.class);
```

which fetches all the MyEntitys, in which a concrete AnotherEntity is referenced. I know this query is wrong. It's just there to show you what I mean.

I do not want to solve this with a bidirectional mapping.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = 
    em.createQuery("select me from MyEntity me"
                       + " where :anotherentity member of me.anotherEntities", 
                   MyEntity.class);
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed to know!